# unexpected token import without ejecting/updating config

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, es6-modules

Is there any an easy way to configure Create React App so that it will use the pre-configured Jest to use ES6 modules *without* ejecting? I am importing foundation-sites into the project. When I run the first test for the App component, I get the following error:

```
FAIL  src/App/App.test.js 
Test suite failed to run

/node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/js/npm.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import $ from 'jquery';
                                                                                         ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

I've tried installing babel-jest and adding a .babelrc file with presets:["react", "es2015"] with no luck. I didn't know if anyone else had any success using Create-React-App jest tests if one of your node_modules used JS modules.

Answer (score 0):

On current version of CRA (1.5.2) tests with imports work outside of the box.
Did you make any changes? If yes, maybe you can share the code of the test or make an easy reproduction?

My suggestion is to make sure you don't have another version of jest installed locally or globally (CRA does not like that as far as I know).

Comment: Ok, I was able to reproduce your issue, and it seems that dist code of foundation sites has non-transpiled code and since CRA does not touch node_modules it's throwing an error.

As far as I know there's no easy way to do this without ejecting.
You can try messing with `react-app-rewired`, but I wouldn't call it "an easy way".

But looking at [this PR](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/pull/10864) the issue will be resolved on the foundation side in the 6.5.* versions.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I concluded the same thing. Previously, my team just ejected. I don't see a better way. After ejecting I can configure as I need to. I don't like having to eject when CRA says it should be a last resort but you have to do what you have to do. It would be nice if CRA had a simple way to achieve this without waiting for Node to support ES modules.